# Dotted or dashed lines possible with ZPL II?

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I'm working on creating a new ZPL label, and would like to draw a dashed line, but I haven't found any information on how to do that or if it's even possible.

Am I asking too much of ZPL?

Comment: If you're making a program to generate the ZPL, you can always make your own function to loop a bunch of very small lines.

Comment: I'm not building a program, just a single label. However, based on my research, it sounds like your solution is essentially what I need to do anyway. I'm going to have to manually create and align a whole bunch of little lines to form a dashed lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a dashed pattern with `^GF`. It's not the most efficient way in terms of ZPL code size, but it's very easy to amend by hand:

```
^XA
^FO10,10
^GFA,100,100,50,FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000FFFFFF0000^FS
^IS1.png,N
^XZ
```

Result:

> [image]

Comment: I ended up just using `^GB` to create a series of short lines. It worked great, but I think your solution might actually be very slightly more efficient by a handful of bytes, so you get check mark.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the zebra zpl designer program , which allows you to create the label like WYSWYG (what you see is what you get or something like that) and then print it to a file, to have a .prn file to you can inspect the code. And then you can use this site: http://labelary.com/viewer.html to prove it.